# SQL select between 2 dates not working

Tags: sql

I have a column named "Date of Payment" ( a nvarchar(50) ) and I am trying to select all the rows which the date is in the year 2015.

```
Select ID,[Date of Payment]
From mytable
WHERE     ('Date of Payment' BETWEEN '2015/01/1' AND '2015/12/31')
```

When I run the select statement above it doesn't return any rows. The date of payment samples could be 1/1/2015 or 1/1/15 etc.  Is there something wrong with my syntax? TIA

Comment: what dialect is this

Comment: You're comparing the *string* 'Date of Payment' with your dates, not the values in your column. It would also help to tell us the data type of your `Date of Payment` column.

Comment: You are comparing a string to two string values.  You have learned that the letter `'D'` is not between the number `'2'` and the number `'2'`.  I vote to close such questions as an improper use of single quotes (a simple typographic error).

Comment: what is  datatype of Date of Payment column?

Comment: nvarchar(50) is the datatype

Comment: @user1342164 do you expect it to magically do a date compare on string data?  Store dates in date columns, not string columns.

Comment: Sorry guys im not a sql expert just thought it was a simple syntax issue

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: `'Date of Payment'` is a string literal, not a column name, so the WHERE clause will always be false. Use double quotes instead, like `"Date of Payment"`, or square brackets (if MS SQL Server), i.e `[Date of Payment]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use between because your date field is not type DATETIME.

```
Select ID,[Date of Payment]
From mytable
WHERE     [Date of Payment] like '%2015%'
```

Comment: You can skip the first `%` to speed things up a bit, especially if the column is indexed. I.e. do `like '2015%'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the Where clause
If I understood well, you use MS-SQL and in this dialect the field names are enclosed in square brackets , not in single quote marks.

```
Select [ID],[Date of Payment]
From [mytable]
WHERE     ([Date of Payment] BETWEEN '2015/01/01' AND '2015/12/31' )
```

Answer (score 0):

As @MattGibson said, you're comparing the string 'Date of Payment' with your strings (representing dates). That does nothing about the values in your column.

Please check how to store dates in your particular DBMS. Surely you'll need to change datatype in that column and change the comparison you're doing.

PS. Also, please specify which DB are you using.